# Getting Active Directory Domain Services Folder and/or DistingiushedName

Tags: powershell

I'm new to scripting with Powershell for Active Directory, and attempting to pull out users in a list and enumerating their groups; however when I do so the resultant information contains just the name of the group which is duplicated under many differently named OUs. Looking at them in AD Users and Computers under the Member Of tab shows the Name and the Active Directory Domain Services Folder which contains exactly the differentiating info I need, or alternately I could use the DistinguishedName which isn't as nicely formatted for readability but would also work.

Problem with simplified examples: If a group name is the same across different OUs (like "TestUsers") then the script currently dumps multiple group names without differentiation "TestUsers, TestUsers, TestUsers" instead of showing the underlying OUs in a clean format "Michigan\TestUsers, NewYork\TestUsers" or Distinguished Name format "CN=TestUsers,CN=Michigan,etc";"CN=TestUsers,CN=NewYork,etc".

```
$alist = "Name`tAccountName`tDescription`twhenCreated`tAcctEnabled`tGroups`n"
$userlist = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Service Accounts,OU=Information Systems,DC=conteso,DC=local" -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object -Property Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmailAddress,LastLogonDate,Manager,Title,Department,Company,whenCreated,Enabled,MemberOf | Sort-Object -Property Name
$userlist | ForEach-Object {
    $grps = $_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | ForEach-Object {$_.Name} | Sort-Object
    $arec = $_.Name,$_.SamAccountName,$_.Description,$_.whenCreated,$_.Enabled
    $aline = ($arec -join "`t") + "`t" + ($grps -join "`t") + "`n"
    $alist += $aline
}
$alist | Out-File C:\psscripts\service_accounts_groups.csv
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that DistinguishedName already has this information but I think it is easier to just use `Get-AdGroup` to get some friendlier information. A little string manipulation on the `CanonicalName` of the group, while not as efficient maybe, would be easier to work with.

```
$grps = $_.MemberOf | Get-AdGroup -Properties CanonicalName | ForEach-Object{
    $CN = ($_.CanonicalName -Split "/")
    "{0}\{1}" -f $CN[-2],$CN[-1]
}
```

or as a one liner if you prefer.

```
$grps = $_.MemberOf | Get-AdGroup -Properties CanonicalName | ForEach-Object{$CN = ($_.CanonicalName -Split "/"); "{0}\{1}" -f $CN[-2],$CN[-1]}
```

What we do is take the CanonicalName which can be considered the path of the object in Active Directory. Since you only wanted the parent container we split up the path and join only the last two parts. The group object and its container.

Same result could come from just getting the second last element from `CanonicalName` and appending the group name to it. Might look at little nicer

```
$grps = $_.MemberOf | Get-AdGroup -Properties CanonicalName | ForEach-Object{"{0}\{1}" -f ($_.CanonicalName -Split "/")[-2],$_.Name}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the "$_.memberof" property already has the Distinguished name, you don't need to pass it to Get-Adgroup again. so simply replace your $grps line like this

```
$grps = $_.MemberOf -replace "CN=","" -replace "OU=","" -replace "DC=","" -replace ",","\" | Sort-Object
```

Or if you still want to proceed with your approach, use it with `distinguishedname` property instead of `name` property - like this (with the text replace)

```
$grps = $_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | ForEach-Object {$_.DistinguishedName -replace "CN=","" -replace "OU=","" -replace "DC=","" -replace ",","\"} | Sort-Object
```

Or as suggested by Matt in the comment, simply use `canonicalname` property.

```
$grps = $_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup -Properties canonicalname | select -ExpandProperty canonicalname
```

Cheers, GJ

Comment: In your second example you might as well use `CanonicalName` instead of trying to build it again.

Comment: @Matt - Yes, thats a good choice. I just got proceeded with the similar approach in 1st example. I'll update the answer with your solution as well.

Comment: Thank you for your examples, I tried out the first one and it worked great, plus looks good if I switch the "\" to a "." instead. You definitely gave me some new things to explore and learn!

Comment: If you think it is working as per your needs you may mark this as an answer.